# Symfony2: DateTime object not working

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I am working with the DateTime object and have this problem to obtain the activity of a specific day.

In the controller I do the following query:

```
$date = new \DateTime('today');
$activity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:myEntity')->findOneBy(array(
    'activity_date' => $date
));
```

Result for this query is `null`, but when I define the parameter date in this way:

```
$date = new \DateTime('Wednesday, ‎January ‎14, ‎2015');
```

I get the activity that matches this date. Why doesn't `today` work?

Comment: Im not too sure if `'today'` is valid and im pretty sure you want `'now'`. If you want the current system day/time then you don't even need to supply an argument. Additionally im not sure that Doctrine does autoconversion from `DateTime` to the proper string for the query.. I have always used `DateTime::format` to prepare the SQL date format (otherwise if you only care about date but your column has the H:i:s as well it will use the time in your object as well i would think). But I may have just missed that feature.

Comment: @prodigitalson Doctrine accepts DateTime objects with no issue. `today` is a valid [relative format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) and [works properly](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17a408e0dba356b545f447c69559622d3dd90790)

Comment: OP, can you post your resulting runnable SQL queries using the Symfony profiler from the two different formats?

Comment: Also, are you sure your system has its date set correctly? What is the output of `date` in your shell?

Comment: Yes, apparently this is the problem, the output of the hour, bad, one day in advance over the current time. To fix this, use the following: $date=new \DateTime('today - 1 day'). But nothing, any other recommendations.

Comment: You haven't answered my questions. What is the output of `date` in your shell? You can't fix the time of your system? " the output of the hour, bad, one day in advance over the current time" what does this mean?

Answer (score -3):

I believe that commenter `@prodigitalson` is right. When you say `today` that is in fact `now` which is formatted with `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Now, if your DBMS column is of type `date`, DBMS will first normalize two values and only then proceed with comparing.

If your incoming parameter has a value of `2014-01-14 16:47:20`, comparing it to DBMS value of `2014-01-14 00:00:00` will **no match the record**.

Try the following:

```
$date = new \DateTime(); // no need for explicit `today`
$date->setTime(0,0,0); // reset hours, minutes and seconds to 0

$activity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:myEntity')->findOneBy(array(
    'activity_date' => $date
));
```

Will this work?

Comment: Why would you use `$date = new \DateTime(); $date->setTime(0,0,0);`, when `today` keyword already sets time to `00:00:00` ?

Comment: `Wednesday, Jan 14, 2015` == `today` != `now`. But `Wednesday, Jan 14, 2015` == `today` _only_ if the server knows `today` to be `Wednesday, Jan 14, 2015`